# Stereo amplifier to single speaker

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers, stereo

Okay so I'm new to all of this and I only have some basic knowledge. My problem is that I have an Amplifier board TDA7492P that outputs 2x25W with a minimum of 4ohm impedance. But I only have one speaker that is 130W max and 35nom with 4ohm impedance. So my first question here is can I even run it? and the second one is how can I connect it to both channels at the same time so I get all the sound.

Comment: There is no rational answer to this irrational line of thinking. VTC.

Answer (score 6):

That chip has two bridged mode outputs. Neither side of the speaker is connected to ground. It will be best to sum the line-level signals rather than the power-level.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi7mLg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Left: intended mode of operation. Right: Modified for single-channel use.*

How it works:

- R1 and R2 (1k to 10k should be fine but both the same) will give the average of the sum of the left and right signals.
- Feed the averaged signal to the input of the left channel and connect the speaker to the output.
- Ground the right channel input to prevent stray noise generating an output.

---

Response to comments:

> So if I understand this we bridged the two channels into one and added resistors because bridging makes the speaker's independence 2 ohm? But then why do we add 2 x 1 k-ohm and not just 2x 1 ohm?

If you look at my Figure 1 right side again you will see that we are not bridging the amplifier at all. In fact we are discarding half of it.

[image]

*Figure 2. Internals of one channel of the TDA7492P. All the internals of the amplifier chip get between the input and speakers amplifying both the voltage and current to drive the low resistance loud speakers.*

The signal feeding into the amplifier is "line level" and typically < 1 V or so and it's power only a few mW. It is much simpler to work with signals at this level rather than at high power levels coming out of the amplifier. 
The amplifier output could be up to the rated 25 W with voltages equal to the supply voltage.

R1 and 2 effectively average the two input signals and feed them into one of the amplifier channels. This is what you want.

---

An analogy:

[image]

*Photo 1. A twin-engined outboard engine boat.*

- I have a boat. (I don't).
- It has two outboard engines (the amplifiers).
- I have only one propeller (the speaker).
- I have two throttles (the left and right stereo input signals).
- I want to disable the engine with no propeller. I disconnect the throttle connection. (The right side amplifier input is grounded.)
- I connect the two throttles to the left engine using a linkage that averages the two throttles. If one is at 100% and the other at 0% I get 50% power. This is what R1 and R2 are doing.
- It works although I'm reduced to half power because I've only one engine (amplifier) and it pulls to one side because the drive (audio) is now coming from one propeller (speaker).

Note that it is far simpler to manipulate the throttle signals than to manipulate the two motor output shafts into one propeller.

---

Schematic from comments:

Sorry, I missed the schematic link in your comments.

[image]

*Figure 3. OP's idea.*

This won't work.

- You have shorted out each of the P and N amplifiers in the stereo pairs.
- You have shorted out the loudspeaker.
- You have 1 kΩ in series with 4 Ω. This will divide the output power (if you fix the other problems) to 4/1000. With a 35 W amplifier you would get 140 mW out. This might be enough for a pair of headphones.

Comment: So if i get this right and im not sure I do. Do I need to add the resistor ON the amp board itself? Is it possible to do it outside te board because as i said i don't really have a lot of experience in this and I'm just starting to learn all of this.
I was thinking something like this if this would even work :)
![schematic](http://prntscr.com/hsft5v)

Comment: You can add the resistors anywhere reasonably close to the board or on the board. Connect the input signal screen wires to the 'ground' terminals.

Comment: Thank you, but I have one more stupid question. So if I understand this we bridged the two channels into one and added resistors because bridging makes the speaker's independence 2ohm? But then why do we add 2x 1 kOhm and not just 2x 1ohm? I might be missing some small thing as I said I'm just getting into all of this :) and thank you again for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: See the update.

Comment: ... and I've thrown in a free analogy.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are trying to say and I see now why my schematic wouldn't work. But as I have no technical knowledge I still don't know how to to it... sorry haha i mean I understand what you are trying to say but i have no idea where to physically put the resistors I understand the 1 figure but only in theory in practice, i have a physical amp board already assembled I just thought I would put some wires in and it would be done now I think I'll just buy another speaker and be done with it... :/

Answer (score 1):

> can I even run it?

If you mean *"can I run a 35 W speaker with a 25 W amp"*, then yes.  The output just won't be as loud as it could be if driven by a amp that can produce 35 W of output.  Other than the top volume being a little lower, no harm will be done and no parts will be abused.

> how can I connect it to both channels at the same time so I get all the sound

If by "all the sound" you mean sound volume as if the speaker was driven from a 50 W amp, then the answer is "You can't".  Two outputs of this type of amp can not be connected together to add their combined output power.

If by "all the sound" you mean the content from both the left and right channels, then do what Transistor described in his answer.